# How do I add a mention ability when using a command such us "rate @user" discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to add a command that could "funnyrate" member's in my server. however when I use the command it only replies to the person who wrote the command, how do I make it so that I could "funnyrate @anotheruser"?
here is the code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    var rating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    message.reply(`you are ${rating}% funny`);
}

module.exports.help = {
  name:"funnyrate"
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to ping the person mentioned in the command? What do you expect to happen when running your command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Message#mentions` with `Message#channel#send()`

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    var rating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    var mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (!mentionedMember) return message.reply(`you are ${rating}% funny`);
    return message.channel.send(`${mentionedMember}, you are ${rating}% funny`);
}

module.exports.help = {
  name:"funnyrate"
}
```